# add an additional item to an array in Drupal Settings javascript from php

Tags: javascript

I've got a hook_node_view which I'm trying to add a property of the node to an array that I have created in the Drupal.settings

```
drupal_add_js(array('embedded_videos'=>array()));
```

So in the node_view I can do

```
function mymod_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
if($node->type == 'video'){
   drupal_add_js(array(
    'vimn_video' => array('embedded_videos' => $node->nid,
      ),
    ),
  'setting');
}
```

But this overwrites what is in there, whereas I want to add to the array. Because this node_view is running multiple times as I have 2 video nodes embedded into an article node.

Any ideas appreciated. I am new to the usage of Drupal.settings javascript api.

edit: The issue was that I needed to put $node->nid into an array array($node->nid), then it will add an item to the array rather than overwriting it.

Answer (score 4):

Your first declaration should indicate that you are passing a setting to drupal_add_js():

```
drupal_add_js(array('your_module' => array()), 'setting');
```

Then you can add other properties to your array in hook_node_view():

```
function your_module_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    $your_array = array(
      'vimn_video' => array(
        'embedded_videos' => array($node->nid), // NOTE: $node->nid as an array
      ),
    );
    drupal_add_js(array('your_module' => $your_array), 'setting');  
}
```

You can retrieve the properties from javascript as:

```
Drupal.settings.your_module.vimn_video.embedded_videos; // an array with node ids.
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you use **hook_js_alter** (and possibly drupal_js_defaults)
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7

Something like (untested of course):

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if ( true ) {
    $javascript['settings']['vimn_video']['embedded_videos'] = $node->nid;
  }
}
```